# why isn't masonry loading my database data?

Tags: php, html, json, masonry

Can anyone give me a working example of a html page loading it's content with json data using masonry plugin?

I have this code but it doesn't load anything :

PHP file :

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "*", "*", "scratch");
mysqli_query($con,"SET NAMES UTF8");  //é preciso meter isto em utf-8 senão não manda nada
if (!$con)
    {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
    } 
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY IdPost DESC") or die;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
    $output[]=$row;
  }  

print(json_encode($output, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

So, it gets me this json :

[{"IdPost":"5","Title":"Social Networks Blueprints","PostContent":"Main Social Networks Blueprints","TypePublic":"1","IdCategory":"1","PostDate":"2014-11-16 00:00:00","PostImage":"http://static.ddmcdn.com/gif/storymaker-best-hubble-space-telescope-images-20092-514x268.jpg","IdUser":"2"},{"IdPost":"3","Title":"* New iPhone 5 *","PostContent":"Check out this new piece of pure technology","TypePublic":"1","IdCategory":"1","PostDate":"2014-11-16 00:00:00","PostImage":"http://images.visitcanberra.com.au/images/canberra_hero_image.jpg","IdUser":"3"},{"IdPost":"2","Title":"* New Samsung Galaxy S4 *","PostContent":"The specs are awesome. Check this graphic","TypePublic":"1","IdCategory":"1","PostDate":"2014-11-16 00:00:00","PostImage":"http://www.studiotv.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Klimas-website-edited.jpg","IdUser":"2"}]

now the HTML part of the FILE that matters:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="main-inner">
        <div id="container" class="js-masonry"data-masonry-options='{ "columnWidth": 2, "itemSelector": ".item" }'>
            <div class="gride-sizer"></div>
            <!--Open Modal faz o pop-up-->
            <div class="item open-modal">
            <!-- CCODIGO PARA 1 SECÇÃO DE COMMENTS -->
                <a href="#"> 
                    <img src="images/A.jpg"><img>
                </a>
                <div class="pinMeta">
                    <p class="pinDescription">
                    Tenda suspensa na arvore! O sonho de qualquer campista (ou qualquer bêbado) como eu! Não perca tempo, reserve já a sua!
                    </p>
                    <div class="pinSocialMeta">
                        <a class="socialItem likes" href="#">                         
                            1 like
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="pinUserAttribution">
                    <a class="attributionItem firstAttribution " href="#">
                        <img class="attributionImg" style="" src="images/profile.jpg"></img>
                        <span class="attributionTitle">
                            Publicado por
                        </span>
                        <span class="attributionName">
                            Pihh
                        </span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="attributionItem lastAttribution " href="#">
                        <img class="attributionImg" style="" src="images/profile.jpg"></img>
                        <span class="attributionTitle">
                            em
                        </span>
                        <span class="attributionName">Categoria 1</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

It might miss  a div or two because I copy-pasted it but when using the masonry plugin without json ( for fixed values it loads perfectly ).

now the CSS file:

```
#container .grid-sizer  { width:100%;}
#container .item        { width:15%; margin: 14px 7px 0px; background-color:#fff; border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px; box-shadow: 0px 4px 5px #888888; }
#container .item img    { width:100%; height:400%%; border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px; }
#container .item img:hover { background:none repeat scroll rgba(255,255,255,0.1) }
#container .item w2 { width:200%; }
/*placed .open-modal at 400px so I can garantee that page remains in same position on when modals opened*/
.open-modal{
    position: relative;
    top: 400px;
}
```

So, this is it, I'm having quite a trouble to make this working and I'm totaly blank on this (  probably because I'm new to html and CSS, my expertise is on android - even the asynk tasks of android are really more easy for me and probably I'm having problems in that but if some one could give me a piece of working code I'll be trully greatfull and start to try to understand it .

Best regards,

Pihh

EDIT: I totally forgot the js part !

```
 <script>   
     var body = $('body');

    toggleModal = function () {
        body.toggleClass('body-locked');
        modal_container.toggleClass('dp-block');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost/website2/posts.php",
            data: '{ "pIdPost":' + $(this).attr('data-item') + ' }',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                var Posts = response;
              //  var Posts = response.d;
                var $boxes;
                $.each(Posts, function (index, post) {
                    $boxes = $('<img src="' + post.PostImage + '" />');
                    $('#modal-main').html($boxes); //
                   // $('.modal-userthumb').attr('src', post.Users.UserImage);
                   // $('.modal-descriptioncreator').text(post.Users.Name + ' ' + post.Users.Surname);
                    $('.modal-descriptiontimeago').text('• 4 days ago');
                    $('.modal-descriptioncontent').text(post.PostContent);
                });
                    $('#container').append($boxes);
                    $('#container').masonry('appended', $boxes, true);
                    $('#container').masonry();


            },
            failure: function (msg) {
                alert(msg);
            }
        });
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: What is the connection between your JSON and the html page? There's a javascript piece we need to see.

Comment: That actually was the main part of this question, sorry !

I' updating the question right now !